# How can I switch column MultiIndex in a Pandas DataFrame but group on the inner level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this DataFrame as an example (this is code I got from the pandas docs):

```
import pandas._testing as tm


def unpivot(frame):
    N, K = frame.shape
    data = {
        "value": frame.to_numpy().ravel("F"),
        "variable": np.asarray(frame.columns).repeat(N),
        "date": np.tile(np.asarray(frame.index), K),
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date", "variable", "value"])


df = unpivot(tm.makeTimeDataFrame(3))
df['value2'] = df['value'] * 2
df.pivot(index = 'date', columns = 'variable')
```

The column headers/index are as such after the pivot:

```
                        value               value2
variable   A     B     C     D    A    B    C    D 
date
1          1     2     3     4    1    2    3    4
2          1     2     3     4    1    2    3    4
3          1     2     3     4    1    2    3    4
```

and I would like them to look like this:

```
variable A               B               C               D    
         value value2    value value2    value value2    value value2 
date
1          1     1       2      2         3     3         4      4
2          1     1       2      2         3     3         4      4
3          1     1       2      2         3     3         4      4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df = (
    df.pivot(index='date', columns='variable')
        .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

`df`:

```
variable       A            B            C            D       
           value value2 value value2 value value2 value value2
date                                                          
2000-01-03     1      2     2      4     3      6     4      8
2000-01-04     1      2     2      4     3      6     4      8
2000-01-05     1      2     2      4     3      6     4      8
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.tile(['2000-01-03 00:00:00', '2000-01-04 00:00:00',
                     '2000-01-05 00:00:00'], 4),
    'variable': np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 3),
    'value': np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], 3),
    'value2': np.repeat([2, 4, 6, 8], 3)
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

`df`:

```
         date variable  value  value2
0  2000-01-03        A      1       2
1  2000-01-04        A      1       2
2  2000-01-05        A      1       2
3  2000-01-03        B      2       4
4  2000-01-04        B      2       4
5  2000-01-05        B      2       4
6  2000-01-03        C      3       6
7  2000-01-04        C      3       6
8  2000-01-05        C      3       6
9  2000-01-03        D      4       8
10 2000-01-04        D      4       8
11 2000-01-05        D      4       8
```